# How to manage multiple timers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

Below is the coding I use for one count up timer:

```
var sec = 0;
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }       
function setTime()
{
    document.getElementById("seconds0").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes0").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
}

var timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

If I have two timers, I write like this:

```
var sec = 0;
var sec1 = 0;
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }       
function setTime()
{
    document.getElementById("seconds0").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes0").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
}
function setTime1()
{
    document.getElementById("seconds1").innerHTML=pad(++sec1%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes1").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec1/60,10));
}

var timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
var timer1 = setInterval(setTime1, 1000);
```

Actually the timer I use is to show waiting time of people. The number of people is a unknown variable. Means that it can be from 1 - 100. So, one people is one timer. Below is the function I written.

```
showWait = function(){
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) 
    {                 
            html += '<div id="numbers" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">'+i+'</div>';
            html += '<div id="qtime" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></span><div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Waiting</div><div id="waittime"><label id="minutes'+i+'">00</label>:<label id="seconds'+i+'">00</label></div></div>';
            html += '</div>';
    }
$('#waitnumber').html(html);
}
```

So, I don't think the way to create more timer is to keep repeating same function over and over again, right? It can't be if 100 people then there is 100 timers, right? Is there any simpler way to manage multiple timers?

Comment: mplungjan, he knows how to make multiple timers, already did it, if you dont noticed, his question is how to make it more simplier

Comment: There are literally hundreds if not thousand OO timers out there. Pick one that is well tested instead of making your own unless it is for education purposes, which still means look at a well built one

Answer (score 2):

i guess that every interval has `1000` ms waiting time, so you dont need multiple timers just one and in this one timer do what you need for every person

```
var sec = [time0, time1, time2 ....];
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }       
function setTime()
{
    for(person = 0; person < numberOfPeople; person++)
    {
        document.getElementById("seconds" + person).innerHTML=pad(++sec[person]%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes" + person).innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec[person]/60,10));
    }
}
var timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

Comment: This is a good answer... but the timer all started at the same time right? What if I want the timer to start at different time?

Comment: interval will execute your function only for people lower than numberOfPeople, so for people with number higher than that will start counting next second you increase numberOfPeople. If you want to more complex managing, then will be another logic right for you

Answer (score 2):

IF your time interval for each person is going to be fixed then I would suggest you should run only one timer of 1000ms and define certain variables for each person i.e something like that

```
var persons = [
    {id : 0, min : 0, sec : 0, othercounts: 0},
    {id : 1, min : 0, sec : 0, othercounts: 0}
]
```

and on the execution of timer function, just iterate through the array or (any data structure that you feel comfortable with) and increment the time counter variables for every person and refresh the dom.

your timer function will be like:

```
function setTime(){
    persons.forEach(function(p){
    p.min ++; 
    // your logic
    document.getElementById("seconds"+ e.id).innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes" + e.id).innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
    });
}
```

and register the interval only once i.e on document load event or on your custom event

```
var timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

on arrival of new person, just push the person object into the persons array.

This is just one way, there can be more better solution by rendering the html  only once at the end of the loop.

Comment: How about the setInterval function? You did not mentioned about that sir.

Comment: you can register an interval on document load or when you will start the timer depending on your logic
setInterval function will have the forEach loop, if the loop is empty, then nothing will happen, else it will be iterated, change the variables and update the dom. let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same question. I came up with a solution but I wanted to see if the internet had any better solutions. My solution was to create a singleton class to manage timers and another timer class that stores information about specific timer instances. Here's a low level example of my implementation.

Singleton TimerManager Class

```js
// singleton class to manage timers.
class TimerManager {
  #timers;
  constructor() {
    if (TimerManager.instance === null) {
      TimerManager.instance = this
      this.#timers = [];
      this.tickInterval = null;
      this.active = false;
    } else {
      return TimerManager.instance;
    }
  }

  #stopAllTimers() {
    this.#timers.forEach((timer) => {
      if (timer.isRunning) {
        timer.isRunning = false;
      }
    });
  }

  start() {
    if (!this.active) {
      console.log("Starting the TimeManager");
      this.active = true;
      this.tickInterval = setInterval(
        (self) => {
          self.#timers.forEach((timer) => {
            if (timer.isRunning) {
              timer.seconds--;
              console.log({
                id: timer.timerId,
                sec: timer.seconds,
              });
            }
          });
        },
        1000,
        this
      );
    }
  }

  stop() {
    if (this.active) {
      this.active = false;
      clearInterval(this.tickInterval);
      this.#stopAllTimers();
      console.log("TimeManager has stopped");
    }
  }

  // crud operations

  // create
  addTimer(timer) {
    if (timer instanceof Timer) {
      console.log(`adding timer: ${timer.timerId}`);
      this.#timers.push(timer);
    } else {
      console.warn(
        "The argument passed into addTimer must be an instance of Timer"
      );
    }
    return this;
  }

  // read
  getTimerById(timerId) {
    const res = this.#timers.filter((timer) => timer.timerId === timerId);

    if (res.length === 1) {
      return res[0];
    } else {
      console.warn(`could not find timer with the id of ${timerId}`);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // update
  updateTimerById(timerId, updates) {
    this.getTimerById(timerId).update(updates);
  }

  // delete
  removeTimerById(id) {
    console.log(`Removing timer: ${id}`);
    this.#timers = this.#timers.filter((timer) => id !== timer.timerId);
    console.log(this.#timers);
  }
}
TimerManager.instance = null;
```

The choice to use a singleton class here was that so all timers could be updated with one setInterval that gets stored in the tickInterval property. Being a singleton class there will only ever be one instance of this class. That being said I left all the logic of the individual timers to the Timer class that I'll show you next. The `TimeManager.getTimerById()` allows us to access timers from the list and call any of the Timer methods. I also used a static property `numTimers` to keep track and autoincrement the `timerId` of new Timers as they are created.

```js
class Timer {
  static numTimers = 0;
  constructor(seconds = 30) {
    Timer.numTimers++;
    this.timerId = `timer${Timer.numTimers}`;
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.initialSeconds = seconds;
    this.seconds = seconds;
  }

  tick() {
    if (this.isRunning) {
      this.seconds--;
    }
  }

  activateTimer() {
    console.log(`Starting timer: ${this.timerId}`);
    this.isRunning = true;
    return this;
  }

  reset() {
    this.seconds = this.initialSeconds;
    return this;
  }

  update(update) {
    if (update.hasOwnProperty("seconds")) {
      this.seconds = update.seconds;
    }
    return this;
  }

  stop() {
    console.log(`Stoping timer: ${this.timerId}`);
    this.isRunning = false;
    return this;
  }
}
```

So that's where I'm at with the problem. Of course you can add the pad method in and even change the way the Timer object works. I have an entirely different Timer class that I want to use with this TimerManager class. I just created this simpler one as a proof of concept for myself. If anyone has any better suggestions on how to manage multiple timers in a javascript app please let me know.

Also I'd avoid using parseInt() instead of Math.floor() to calculate the minutes. Check it out on jsBench.me Math.floor() performs about 70% better.